# How can I track button clicks on a site that can't use Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, event-tracking, goal-tracking, velo

I will start by saying that I have fair experience in HTML, but please keep the technical terms to a bare minimum. Pretend you're explaining it to a child. :-)

I used Wix.com to make my site (Wix is a place to easily design websites and has little HTML capabilities, since it's all based on being able to easily design a site with no HTML knowledge). You can add a Google Analytics tracking code, so i can see the number of clicks on the site, but that's about all. Apparently you can't change the code to be able to see button clicks on the site etc. (or maybe you can?...)

This is what I need above anything else:

On the site are a few "sign up now" buttons. When someone clicks it, they go to a signup page on an external site. I need to be able to track who clicks these buttons and when.

Ideally it's all tracked within google but apparently it doesn't work on wix.

Priorities:

1. Somehow it works with Google Analytics on Wix. It would have to be if somehow I can track it with Analytics without putting a code on the site itself. Don't know if or how that would work.
2. If not Google, is there a simple 3rd party Analytics site that could track the number of clicks on these buttons to external pages? It would be best if I can get the IP addresses of the clickers as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is fairly easy, try customerlabs.co/google-analytics-event-tracking which can directly help you to send data about the users when they click event tracking.

eg: [image: You can see the tracked events directly here in google analytics]

Answer (score 0):

Wix supports 3 types of goal tracking for your site: Destination, Duration and Pages/Screens per session. Currently, Wix doesn't support an Event tracking goal.